# How do I store and access multiple occurrences of items, but with different values?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, data-structures

I want a data structure to store 3 things - book name, score given to the book by a user, and a count of how many users have given that book the unique score:

```
BookName    Score   Count
Book1:      7       1
            4       2
Book2:      5       1
            9       1
            3       2
            2       1
Book3:      9       3
Book4:      8       1
            9       1
            4       2
```

Which data structure allows me to store this info and access them easily?

I tried using dictionaries for this, like so:

```
my_dict = [{'BookName':'Book1', 'Score': 7, 'NumberOfTimes':2}, 
       {'BookName':'Book2', 'Score': 4, 'NumberOfTimes':1}, 
       {'BookName':'Book1', 'Score': 5, 'NumberOfTimes':3}]
```

But when I want to display all instances of `Book1`, it shows only the first instance:

```
my_dict['BookName'=='Book1']
>>> {'BookName': 'Book1', 'NumberOfTimes': 2, 'Score': 7}
```

So, which is the best data structure, or what is the best way, to do this?

Comment: Key invalid `'BookName'`, try `{"Books":{"Book1":......, "Book2": ...., ..."},....}`

Comment: You want a dictionary of lists, where book names are the keys and lists of tuples `(score,count)` are the values. A dictionary of `Counter`s may be an even better choice.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the use case, just for one case you mentioned, storing the values in array justifies as given in below answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a data structure as follows:

```
book_dict = {
    'Book1': [{'NumberOfTimes':2, 'Score':7}, {'NumberOfTimes':3, 'Score':5}],
    'Book2': [{'NumberOfTimes':1, 'Score':5}]
}
```

this way you can access all the instances of a particular book using `book_dict['Book1']`
You will also be able to iterate over a book.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather keep it simple and use the below:

```
book_dict = {"Book1" : {7:1,4:2}, "Book2" : {5:1,9:1,3:2,2:1}}

for k,v in book_dict.items():
    print (k, v)

book_dict["Book1"][7] = book_dict["Book1"][7]+1
print (book_dict["Book1"])
book_dict["Book1"][8] = 1
print (book_dict["Book1"])
```

Result:

```
Book1 {7: 1, 4: 2}
Book2 {5: 1, 9: 1, 3: 2, 2: 1}
{7: 2, 4: 2}
{7: 2, 4: 2, 8: 1}
```

Comment: But how do I add a new book in this dictionary? When I do `book_dict['Book3'][{'NumberOfTimes':2, 'Score':8}]`, it gives the following error: `KeyError: 'Book3'`

Comment: You can simply use  `book_dict["Book3"] = {8:2}`

Comment: The problem with that is, if I ten want to input multiple scores to `Book3`, only the last one is kept: `book_dict["Book3"] = [{'NumberOfTimes':8, 'Score':2}]`
`book_dict["Book3"] = [{'NumberOfTimes':7, 'Score':9}]`

Comment: you can use `book_dict["Book3"][8] = 1` instead and it will always add or update to the current score/times pair